# Style for creating IEnumerable unions

Tags: c#, coding-style, linq

There isn't any cool LINQ sugar for creating unions. The `Enumerable.Union()` method is usually called like this:

```
var bigList = list1.Union(list2);
```

The alternative is to call `Enumerable.Union()` which can be more readable:

```
var bigList = Enumerable.Union(list1, list2);
```

However neither of these methods are very stylish (more importantly, readable) when scaling out The following is probably the best method:

```
var reallyBigList = list1.Union(list2).Union(list3);
```

Which can result in some messy method chaining. Alternatives need incidental variables:

```
var list1and2 = list1.Union(list2);
var reallyBigList = list1and2.Union(list3);
```

or

```
var list1and2 = Enumerable.Union(list1, list2);
var reallyBigList = Enumerable.Union(list1and2, list2);
```

Is there a clean way of setting up these more complex unions? Would an extension like `Enumerable.Union(params IEnumerable<T> collections)` (used like `var reallyBigList = Enumerable.Union(list1, list2, list3)`) be better?

Answer (score 4):

I don't consider the method chaining option messy at all. Sure, something like

```
 var reallyBigList = (from ... where ... select ...).Union(from ... where ... select)...
```

can easily get unreadable, but, on the other hand,

```
 var mp3s = from ... where ... select ...
 var videos = from ... where ... select ...
 var alreadyProcessed = from ... where ... select ...

 var toDo = mp3s.Union(videos).Except(alreadyProcessed)
```

reads quite naturally. So, when using *well-named* intermediate variables, the method chaining approach is extremely readable.

Answer (score 1):

The method chaining style is pretty readable, in my opinion. Certainly you could write your own extension method to take many `IEnumerable<T>`.

Here's an example using iteration. Recursion works too, but I didn't like it as much.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyUnion<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> original, params IEnumerable<T>[] toUnion)
{
    var enumerable = original;
    foreach (var other in toUnion)
    {
        enumerable = enumerable.Union(other);
    }

    return enumerable;
}
```

Comment: or you could flatten the `toUnion` array to factor away the loop - `return original.Union(toUnion.SelectMany(x => x));`

Comment: @MattDavey: Note that joining sets in `toUnion` and then doing the union has a different performance impact than computing the union in a loop. Which one will be faster depends on the context.

Comment: @MainMa agreed, I didn't make any claims about performance, I was merely pointing out there was a more concise way to write the code.

Comment: I don't think the call to `AsEnumerable()` is necessary here.